# Dojo build result in empty cache

Tags: build, dojo

After making a dojo build, on files where there is a **dojo/text** I got thing like this:

```
require({cache:{
     'url:Dialogs/logOutTimeout.html':"undefined"}});
﻿define("dojo/text!Dialogs/logOutTimeout.html",...
```

The dijit part of the library build ok, with the templates embedded. I can't find what makes it to be included.

Comment: How did you get this? What is your profile.js? What dojo version?

Answer (score 0):

i have seen empty build files when using reserved words at keys for objects. the following would do it

```
{class:"foo"}
```

when it should be like :

```
{'class':"foo"}
```

I would also take a close look at the output of the build tool